# Writing an algorithm for filtering spatial data based on the local coefficient of variations in R

Tags: r, algorithm, filter

I'm trying to write an algorithm for filtering spatial data based on the local coefficient of variations within a search radius. If the number of points with CVs over 25% equals to the total number of points within a search radius, the centre point will be classified as a local outlier or a noise. But I currently stuck on calculating the number of points within a search radius.  Codes below:

```
test_data <- XXX

# calculate the coefficient of variations in the local neighbour 

CV <- function(mean, sd){(sd/mean)*100}

LocalCV = sapply(1:length(test_data), 
                function(pt) 
                {d = spDistsN1(test_data, test_data[pt,])
                return(CV(mean=mean(test_data[d < 5,]$Z),
                          sd=sd(test_data[d < 5,]$Z)))})

LocalCV[LocalCV > mean(LocalCV, na.rm = T)] <- NA

Temprory.df <- na.omit(data.frame(test_data, LocalCV))

coordinates(Temprory.df) <- c("coords.x1","coords.x2")

# If the total number of CVs over 25% equals to 
# the total number of CVs within a search radius
# then return TRUE or 1

Num.CV = sapply(1:length(Temprory.df), 
         function(pt) {d = spDistsN1(Temprory.df, Temprory.df[pt,])
             return(length(Temprory.df[d<5]$LocalCV[Temprory.df$LocalCV>25])
                                       ==length(Temprory.df[d<5]$LocalCV))})
```

Then I got an error message:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(x@data, i, j, ..., drop = FALSE) : 
undefined columns selected
Called from: `[.data.frame`(x@data, i, j, ..., drop = FALSE)
```

Reproducible example:

```
    coords.x1 coords.x2       Z
1    1803299   5786242 28.1757
2    1803297   5786242 30.6624
3    1803295   5786241 37.4547
4    1803293   5786241 39.6034
5    1803290   5786240 34.4702
6    1803288   5786239 38.8357
7    1803286   5786239 31.5278
8    1803284   5786239 20.4700
9    1803281   5786238 19.4517
10   1803279   5786238 24.8794
11   1803277   5786238 26.0178
12   1803274   5786238 30.4886
13   1803272   5786238 27.1075
14   1803270   5786238 27.6069
15   1803268   5786238 23.1940
16   1803268   5786238 10.2322
17   1803269   5786238  0.0000
18   1803270   5786238  0.0000
19   1803272   5786238  0.0000
20   1803274   5786238  0.0000
```

Can anyone help me resolve this issue or give some recommendations please?

Comment: Forgot to change `XXX` to a spatial data frame, but it is not the question here.

Comment: Have you thought about using the RANN::nn2 function? This will return the distances and neighbor row indexes thus, saving you bunch of code. It is also written in C so, is very fast with large data and search neighborhoods.

Comment: No I haven't used this function before, let me give a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful with `test_data`! It was a `SpatialPointsDataFrame` object instead of a `data.frame`! It's different the `length` function over a `SpatialPointsDataFrame` than over a `data.frame`. In the first case `R` will return `20` and in the second `3` (number of columns instead the number of rows). Also, check how to query to get `Num.CV` vector if you want to get values below `d` and above `CV`. Hope this help!

Check the reproducible and commented code below:

```
# Load required libarries
library('sp')

# Make test data
test_data <- data.frame("coords.x1" = c(1803299,1803297,1803295,1803293,1803290,1803288,1803286,1803284,1803281,1803279,1803277,1803274,1803272,1803270,1803268,1803268,1803269,1803270,1803272,1803274),
                        "coords.x2" = c(5786242,5786242,5786241,5786241,5786240,5786239,5786239,5786239,5786238,5786238,5786238,5786238,5786238,5786238,5786238,5786238,5786238,5786238,5786238,5786238),
                        "Z" = c(28.1757,30.6624,37.4547,39.6034,34.4702,38.8357,31.5278,20.4700,19.4517,24.8794,26.0178,30.4886,27.1075,27.6069,23.1940,10.2322,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000)
                        )

# Transform dataframe to SpatialPointsDataFrame object
coordinates(test_data) <- c("coords.x1", "coords.x2")

# Plot data
spplot(test_data, zcol = "Z", main = "Plot test_data")
```

[image: test_data]

```
# calculate the coefficient of variations in the local neighbour
CV <- function(mean, sd) {
  (sd / mean) * 100
}

# Distance threshold
distThreshold <- 5

# CV threshold
CVThreshold <- 25

LocalCV = sapply(X = 1:length(test_data), 
                 FUN = function(pt) {
                   d = spDistsN1(test_data, test_data[pt,])
                   ret = CV(mean = mean(test_data[d < distThreshold, ]$Z), sd = sd(test_data[d < distThreshold, ]$Z))
                   return(ret)
                 })

# Local values with a CV over the mean CV (18.12537) as NA values 
LocalCV[LocalCV > mean(LocalCV, na.rm = TRUE)] <- NA

# Temporary dataframe without local values with a CV over the mean CV
Temprory.df <- na.omit(data.frame(test_data, LocalCV))

# Transform dataframe to SpatialPointsDataFrame object
coordinates(Temprory.df) <- c("coords.x1", "coords.x2")

# Plot SpatialPointsDataFrame without local values with a CV over the mean CV
spplot(Temprory.df, zcol = "LocalCV", main = "Plot points without Local CV values above overall mean CV")
```

[image: plot2]

```
# If the total number of CVs over 25% equals to
# the total number of CVs within a search radius
# then return TRUE or 1

Num.CV = sapply(X = 1:length(Temprory.df), 
                FUN = function(pt) {
                  d = spDistsN1(Temprory.df, Temprory.df[pt,])
                  ret = length(Temprory.df[d<distThreshold & Temprory.df$LocalCV>CVThreshold,]$LocalCV) == length(Temprory.df[d<distThreshold,]$LocalCV)
                return(ret)
                  }
                ) 

# Add num CV as attribute data to Temprory.df
Temprory.df$NumCV <- Num.CV

# Plot NumCV
spplot(Temprory.df, zcol = "NumCV", main = "Plot Num CV")
```

**Note:** the result was that the total number of points that have a `CV` below the overall `mean` CV AND have a distance below `d` AND have a `CV` above `25%` was `0`.

Comment: Thanks Guzmán, the codes work perfect. I'd take out `LocalCV[LocalCV > mean(LocalCV, na.rm = TRUE)] <- NA`. My original idea was to compare local CV with the mean CV but it is difficult to justify that.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternative approach using the RANN::nn2 function. This has the advantage of returning a matrix of the neighbor row indexes and is very fast on large data and search radii. This is neither better or worse that the previous approach, it is just that, in writing neighbor functions such as this, I have found this to be a very fast and efficient way to subset neighbors within a search radius.

If you set k to (n-1) then you return all observations but only row indexes within the search distance, otherwise the value is 0. You can pass i[i>0] to a bracket index of your data to subset the relevant neighbors.

I will use the same example data that @Guzmán used, with the addition of the RANN library.

```
library(sp)
library(RANN)

d <- 5 # Distance threshold
cv <- function(x) { (sd(x, na.rm=T) / mean(x, na.rm=T)) * 100 }

test_data <- data.frame(ID=1:20, X = c(1803299,1803297,1803295,1803293,1803290,1803288,1803286,1803284,1803281,1803279,1803277,1803274,1803272,1803270,1803268,1803268,1803269,1803270,1803272,1803274),
                        Y = c(5786242,5786242,5786241,5786241,5786240,5786239,5786239,5786239,5786238,5786238,5786238,5786238,5786238,5786238,5786238,5786238,5786238,5786238,5786238,5786238),
                        z = c(28.1757,30.6624,37.4547,39.6034,34.4702,38.8357,31.5278,20.4700,19.4517,24.8794,26.0178,30.4886,27.1075,27.6069,23.1940,10.2322,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000))
```

Here we calculate our neighbors matrix. Note that $nn.idx is explicitly returning the neighbors matrix.

```
( nearest <- RANN::nn2(test_data[,1:3], query = test_data[,1:3], k = nrow(test_data)-1, 
                     treetype = c("bd"), searchtype = c("radius"), 
                     radius = d)$nn.idx )
```

Now we can operate on the dataframe using the "nearest" kNN matrix. You can use sapply but I am not sure that it is buying you much here so, I added a simple for loop as an alternative example.

```
# sapply method                  
( local.cv <- sapply(X = 1:nrow(test_data), 
                 FUN = function(i) {
                   local.cv <- vector()
                       nn <- nearest[i,] 
                       local.cv <- append(local.cv, cv( test_data[nn[nn > 0],]$z) ) 
                       return(local.cv)
                 }) )                    

# Simple for loop
local.cv <- vector()
  for(i in 1:nrow(test_data)) {                  
    nn <- nearest[i,] 
    local.cv <- append(local.cv, cv( test_data[nn[nn > 0],]$z) )                     
  }

local.cv[is.nan(local.cv)]<- 0
```

Now, you can muck with the object using the LocalCV column.

```
p = mean(local.cv, na.rm = TRUE) 
( test_data <- data.frame(test_data, LocalCV = local.cv ) )
( test_data <- test_data[-which(local.cv > p),] )
```